# Discord.js member is undefined in welcome message

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to have my bot send a message to a specific channel when someone joins/leaves the server
But it either does not work, or member comes back as undefined

```
client.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
    console.log(member)
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'newcomers')
    welcomeChannel.send (`Goodbye! ${member}`)
})

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'newcomers')
    welcomeChannel.send (`Welcome to Helix Bot Support Server ${member} Check out <#779221752021778443>`)
})
```

here is my code

Comment: do you have an error?

Comment: It brings up no error usually but if I use client.emit for the event it says cant read guild property of undefined

Comment: you should not use client.emit yourself

Comment: Ok noted. I still do not know why member is undefined however

Comment: I just tried the code you posted and it works as expected. It shows the username when they join and leave: https://imgur.com/a/GzNavnN

Comment: wait then why isn't it working for me I am so confused

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using:

```
welcomeChannel.send(`Goodbye! ${member.user.tag}`)
```

and replacing 'welcomeChannel.send (`Welcome to Helix Bot Support Server ${member} Check out <#779221752021778443>`)' with:

```
welcomeChannel.send (`Welcome to Helix Bot Support Server ${member.user.tag} Check out <#779221752021778443>`)
```

Comment: It still did not work
No error
or any message

Comment: Maybe you have to wait until a member leaves/joins

Comment: I had my alternate account leave the server and join back and still nothing

Comment: Is there any errors showing in the console?